# DAG being triggered right after schedule update

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm having a problem while updating DAG schedules. Every time I make some update on schedule_interval, DAG gets triggered even using "captchup=False". I changed for example this:

```
dag = DAG(
    'MY_DAG',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 1,6 * * *',
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False)
```

For this:

```
dag = DAG(
    'MY_DAG',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='30 1,6 * * *',
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False)
```

After this change, DAG got triggered right after. Is there something I can do to avoid this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can try changing the DAG name as well as the `schedule_interval`

Comment: @manesioz sounds promising also! The problem is I can’t change the name since it needs to be the same name of the file :( (and file name can’t be changed in this case :/)

Comment: whats your `start_date`?

Comment: @manesioz start_date is set to a few days ago actually.

Comment: My guess is if you bump the `start_date` forward (i.e. to today, so next run must be tomorrow), it should avoid this behavior.

Comment: @DanielHuang actually that did the work! So now I will make sure I'll update the start_date everytime I update the schedule interval. Thanks Daniel!